# grabbing all arguments after nth argument and concatenating them together in bash

Tags: string, bash, command-line, arguments

So I have a bash script that needs to take an arbitrary number of command line arguments and put them into a single string

Example of what the user would type in:

```
give <environment> <email> <any number of integers separated by spaces>
give testing stuff@things.com 1 2 3 4 5
```

I want to get all of the arguments from $3 to $# and concat them into a string.

My (probably awful) solution right now is

```
if [ $# -gt 3 ]
then
    env="env="$1
    email="email="$2
    entList=""

    for i in {3..$#}
    do
        if [ $i -eq 3 ]
            then
                    entList=$3
                    shift
            fi;
            if [ $i -gt 3 ]
            then
                    entList=$entList","$3
                   shift
            fi;
     done
fi;
```

I handle the case of having only three arguments a bit differently, and that one works fine.

Final value of `$entList` given the example `give testing stuff@things.com 1 2 3 4 5` should be: `1,2,3,4,5`

Right now when i run this i get the following Errors:

```
/usr/local/bin/ngive.sh: line 29: [: {3..5}: integer expression expected
/usr/local/bin/ngive.sh: line 34: [: {3..5}: integer expression expected
```

Lines 29 and 34 are:

```
line 29: if [ $i -eq 3 ]
line 34: if [ $i -gt 3 ]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A common solution is to save the first 3 arguments, say, in variables: `var1="$1"; var2="$2"; var3="$3"` and then use `shift 3` to remove the first 3 arguments, and thereafter use `"$*"` to create a single string containing the other parameters, space separated: `rest="$*"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track.  Here's my suggestion:

```
if [ $# -ge 3 ]; then

  env="$1"
  email="$2"
  entlist="$3"

  while shift && [ -n "$3" ]; do
    entlist="${entlist},$3"
  done

  echo "entlist=$entlist"

else

  echo "Arguments: $*"

fi
```

Note that variables should always be put *inside* quotes.  I'm not sure why you were setting `env=env=$1`, but I suspect that if you want to recycle that value later, you should do it programatically rather than by evaluating the variable as if it were a statement, in case that was your plan.

Answer (score 6):

Skip first three arguments using a subarray:

```
all=( ${@} )
IFS=','
threeplus="${all[*]:3}"
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the assignment to `IFS` and the quoted array with `*` as the subscript causes the first character of the contents of `IFS` to be output between each element of the array.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're getting those error messages is that in:

```
for i in {3..$#}
```

The brace expansion is performed before the parameter expansion and so the following `if` statement is evaluated as:

```
if [ {3..$#} -eq 3 ]
```

which isn't valid.

Change your `for` statement to use the C style:

```
for ((i = 3; i <= $#; i++))
```

Use this style for integer comparison:

```
if (( $# > 3 ))
```

and

```
if (( i == 3 ))
```

and

```
if (( i > 3 ))
```

Put your parameters inside the quotes:

```
env="env=$1"
email="email=$2"
```

and

```
entList="$entList,$3"
```

although the quotes aren't necessary since word splitting isn't performed on the right side of an assignment and you're not assigning special characters such as whitespace, semicolons, pipes, etc.